# Disturbing behavior of shader extensions

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

In order to be compliant with every graphics hardware configuration, I am trying to allow my application to handle either *MRT* rendering or single *gl_FragColor* rendering. I am using the same shaders for both usages by using *GLSL* `#extension` and `#ifdef` preprocessor directives by checking if *GL_EXT_draw_buffers* is defined into the shader. I encountered some troubles when some shaders used this extension and other doesn't. Indeed, the code was called even if the directive was supposed to be false. I decided to create a simple example to check this issue in *ThreeJS* and *WebGL*.

**Method :**

To visually debug if the extension is defined, I am using the following *GLSL* fragment shader code :

```
uniform vec3 diffuse;
uniform float opacity;
void main() {
    #ifdef GL_EXT_draw_buffers
        gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    #else
        gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    #endif
}
```

The directive is added by *ThreeJS* when sending the shader to the *GPU*.

**Debugging :**

Here are some screenshots, detailed with different `THREE.ShaderMaterial` instantiation order and with the following captions :

- 1.1 (upper left) has `extensions.drawBuffers : true`, expected to be **green**
- 1.2 (upper right) has `extensions.drawBuffers : false`, expected to be **red**
- 2 (bottom) has `extensions.drawBuffers : false`, expected to be **red**
- 1.1 and 1.2 are sharing the same user *GLSL* code

(1)[image: Test1](2)[image: Test2](3)[image: Test3](4)[image: Test4]

1. Instancing 1.1, then 1.2, then 2 : **1.2 and 2 are wrong**
2. Instancing 1.2, then 1.1, then 2 : **1.1 is wrong**
3. Instancing 2, then 1.1, then 1.2 : **1.2 is wrong**
4. Instancing 2, then 1.2, then 1.1 : **1.1 is wrong**

Code example here : [Draw Buffer Define Strange Behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/Ludobaka/xb7dp9su/)

**Detecting the problem :**

(1) When creating two different `THREE.ShaderMaterial` sharing the same *GLSL* user code, I am enabling `extension.drawBuffers` to the first and not to the second. However, the second one enters into the `#ifdef` directive. I have looked at *ThreeJS* and the error seems to come from the way of managing new `THREE.WebGLProgram`.

Indeed, when *ThreeJS* routine is going into `WEBGLPrograms.capabilities.acquireProgram`, it only compares user shader code and not the compiled shader code. Two `THREE.ShaderMaterial` with different extension flags are considered identical. It considers only the first shader that has been defined.

(2) Moreover, when creating a new shader with new code checking the same `#ifdef`, it seems to be dependant of the previous shaders extensions. I have no clue about this problem, I tried to check compiled *GLSL* code from *ThreeJS* and nothing seems wrong, this may be a native *WebGL* problem.

I thought I needed to go really deep on this problem and I am not a native speaker. I apologize if it's not totally clear. I will provide any information if you need.

Thank you in advance for contributing to resolve this tricky problem :)

Comment: extensions in WebGL are enabled once per context, not per shader. If you enable an extension at all it is enabled for all shaders. Also, AFAIK three.js just enables all extensions always.

Comment: Does this help you? `materialDrawBuffer.defines[ "DRAW_BUFFER" ] = "";` and then `#ifdef DRAW_BUFFER` instead of `ifdef GL_EXT_draw_buffers`.

Comment: @gman, I accept your answer. But there is still a problem with your explaination. Why the point 2 is colored red in (3)? If WebGL enables extensions per context, it should be rendered green... I will have a look at WebGL specifications today, but it's still really strange. @WestLangley, this solution should work, but don't you think it would be better change the way of creating new shaders in ThreeJS by modifying `WEBGLPrograms.capabilities.acquireProgram` so it also checks enabled extensions ? Already contributed to ThreeJS so I think it will not be hard for me.

Comment: I think my suggestion is the proper solution to your problem. Just because an extension is enabled does not mean a shader _must_ use it.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to answer to this problems :

- Problem (1) : As [@WestLangley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44139025/disturbing-behavior-of-shader-extensions#comment75305029_44139025) suggested, you could use a custom define to solve the problem. Instead of checking `GL_EXT_draw_buffers` you could define a new variable called `DRAW_BUFFER` for instance. It could be better if managed by ThreeJS for each available extension. I will attempt a pull request about it.
- Problem (2) : As [@gman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44139025/disturbing-behavior-of-shader-extensions#comment75299837_44139025) said, and by checking [*WebGL* specifications](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.14), an extension is context enabled and not shader enabled. Because preprocessor directives are compiled once the shader code is sent to the GPU, you must preferably call `glContext.getExtension` before creating any shader program to avoid this kind of problem.

Both problem are heavily related to each other, but I tried to split them to get an easier answer.